# How to get OneSignal Player ID into Caspio table

Tags: javascript, authentication, onesignal, zapier

my original intention was to have zapier run a javascript every time someone registers on my mobile app to insert the player id into a table in caspio for 2 reasons
1) i'm trying to limit the authentication to a signal device and ive deduced this is the only way to do it with what i have to work with
2) i need to know the username that goes with each player id so i can send push notifications to specific users by username. 
the problem is i've scoured the web for 3 days trying to figure out how to make it work and i am lost. 
maybe there is a simper way to do this that i have overlooked but what i need to acomplish is limiting a registration to a single device and hopefully associating a username with a player id.

Other pertinent info:
my app is a series of caspio datapages, nested in 1 caspio html datapage withthe url built into a mobile app by go native. yes i have cheated pretty much every way possible.

Answer (score -1):

I just added an answer about posting data to Caspio tables through the API. You can include that solution in the "Destination and Emails" section of your user registration datapage, in the same place where you define the message to be displayed, go to source and use the code.

[View solution, related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553299/post-javascript-response-to-caspio-table/51160374#51160374)