# POST javascript response to Caspio Table

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

i am trying to Post the player ID from onesignal to a caspio table. I have read dozens of forums etc and cant seem to get it right. Any Ideas? Custom is the Existing parameter for username on this page that i want sent along with the user id.

```
 OneSignal.push(function() { 
OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {

        if (isSubscribed) {
            OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) { 
                $.post(https://xxxxxxxx.caspio.com/rest/v1/tables/User_ID_Test/rows,( User_ID = 'userId' User_Name = '[@custom]' ), function (data));
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Before doing a POST call to Caspio API, you must generate an access token. I will share an AJAX solution which may represent security issues due to you are exposing your secret and client keys, also every call would generate a new token but it could be useful for any non tech user looking for an easy solution.

***If you want a more robust solution, I could recommend the following service***: [Caspio API Library](https://www.futuresuite.net/products/api-library.php)

At this point in time, v2 of Caspio API has been released so I am using this latest version of Caspio Rest API. The steps to run a POST call to Caspio service are these:

1. Include jQuery in your web page head section or in your caspio datapage header. ***Do not include it in both as it may cause conflicts and it could increase the loading time of your page***. [Help to include jQuery in your project](https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_get_started.asp)
2. Generate an access token from Caspio API.
   [Caspio Documentation](https://howto.caspio.com/web-services-api/rest-api/authenticating-rest/) / [$.post() jQuery Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)
3. Run the POST call. [Full Caspio API documentation](https://howto.caspio.com/web-services-api/rest-api/swagger-ui/)

**Complete code is shown bellow**

```js
<script>
var cbIntegrationId = "<your-integration-id>"; //Required
var clientId = "<your-client-id>"; //Required
var clientSecret = "<your-client-secret>"; //Required
var tableName = "<table-name>"; //Required

//Get access token
$.post(
  "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/oauth/token",
  {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret
  },
  function(cbAuth){
    //Run POST call
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://" + cbIntegrationId + ".caspio.com/rest/v2/tables/" + tableName + "/records?response=rows",
      type: 'POST',
      data: '{"<field1>": "<value-to-be-inserted>", "<field2>": "<value-to-be-inserted>"}', //Define record values
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + cbAuth.access_token, //Extracts the access token from the initial authorization call
        "Content-Type": "application/json", //Required, otherwise 415 error is returned
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.Result); //Check the console to view the new added row
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON); //Check the console to view error message if any
      }
    });
  }
);
</script>
```

**I strongly recommend taking a look at [this article](https://howto.caspio.com/web-services-api/creating-a-web-services-api-profile/). Please read about Permissions for your API profile(s)**